# Solve for the area of a parallelogram; given diagonals and a side

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

> Find the area of the parallelogram $ABCD$ with side $AB=10\sqrt{3}$ $cm$ and diagonals $BD=10\sqrt{3}$ $cm$ and $BC=10$ $cm.$

[image]

Using the fact that $AC^2+BD^2=2(AB^2+BC^2)$ we can find the other side of the parallelogram $\Rightarrow BC=10\sqrt{3}$ $cm.$ What is the fast way to solve for the area of $ABCD$ from here? Maybe using $S=\dfrac{AC\cdot BD}{2}$?

Comment: Are you sure of the condition? $AM + MB = 5 + 5\sqrt{3} < 10\sqrt{3} = AB$. Such parallelogram doesn't exist

Comment: For which triangle? Which triangle does not exist?

Comment: $\triangle AMB$. The triangle inequality doesn't hold for it

Comment: Yep, I have just seen that. My mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that triangle $ABD$ is isosceles:
$$[ABCD]=10\sqrt{(10\sqrt3)^2-5^2}=50\sqrt{11}.$$